# How to improve speed and performance on refresh and update ObserveableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to update and refresh an existing ObservableCollection (with approximately 2.3mill objects in the list) with new items retrieved from a SQL procedure. When I get the latest categories, I receive a list with about 72000 items. My function that I have created to update and refresh the collection works really well, but upon many updated elements, it become really slow and has poor performance. How can I do this in a more efficient and better way?

```
 public async Task UpdateAndRefreshContractMetaDataCollection(ObservableCollection<Category> Categories)
    {
        Type type = typeof(Category);       
        var updatedCategories = await GetLatestUpdatedCategories();

        if (updatedCategories .Count != 0)
        {
            try
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var category in updatedCategories )
                {
                    var categoryCopy = Categories.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.ID== category.ID);
                    if (categoryCopy != null)
                    {
                        i+=1;
                        if (!compareLogic.Compare(categoryCopy , category ).AreEqual)
                        {
                            mapper.Map<Category, Category>(category , categoryCopy );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Categories.Add(category );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error updating categories", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As your code already works, and it just needs to be improved, you'll probably get better results if you go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Use gridbag collection and parallel foreach then create OC.

Comment: You need to add these items once, because every time you add an item, `Add` method calls `PropertyChanged`, so you call request for UI update 72000 times in a very short period of time. `ObservableCollection<T>` does not implement `AddRange`, so  you can either find custom wrapper around `ObservableCollection` or copy all elements each time you receive new items.

Comment: No matter of the data source, rendering 72000 items in the UI is going to take a while on the UI thread. Have you measured to ensure that the delay is due to the collection and not in WPF itself?

Answer (score 0):

The FirstOrDefault is a large part of the bottleneck. For every item in updatedcategories you iterate through the main collection. It would be much faster to use a dictionary.

Try this.

```
public async Task UpdateAndRefreshContractMetaDataCollection(ObservableCollection<Category> Categories)
{
    Type type = typeof(Category);
    var updatedCategories = await GetLatestUpdatedCategories();

    var CatDict = Categories.ToDictionary(c => c.ID);

    if (updatedCategories.Count != 0)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var category in updatedCategories)
            {
                var categoryCopy = CatDict.ContainsKey(category.ID) ? CatDict[category.ID] : null;
                if (categoryCopy != null)
                {
                    i += 1;
                    if (!compareLogic.Compare(categoryCopy, category).AreEqual)
                    {
                        mapper.Map<Category, Category>(category, categoryCopy);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Categories.Add(category);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error updating categories", e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with pseudo like working solution.
This is more in declarative way of programming using Linq rather imperative.
Sorry I did not employee the same objects as in your code snip. But tried to make it more understandable with my own objects.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Your categires been passed to the method (new categories I assume)
        List<int> categories = new List<int>();

        // Updated categores you retrieved from the database.
        ObservableCollection<int> updatedCategories  = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        // Select all the none matching categires to be added in the <mapper.Map>
        var notmatching = (from u in updatedCategories  join n in categories on u equals n where !Comparer(u, n) select u).ToList();

        // Select all the matching categires to be added in the <categories> collection
        var matching = (from u in updatedCategories  join n in categories on u equals n where Comparer(u, n) select u).ToList();

        // Addiing notmaching categories to you map
        notmatching.ForEach(i => Map(i));

        // Adding matching categies to your existing Categories collection
        categories.AddRange(matching);

    }

    // Represent 'compareLogic.Compare(categoryCopy , category ).AreEqual'
    static bool Comparer(int a, int b) {
        return a == b;
    }
    // Represent mapper.Map<Category, Category>(category , categoryCopy );
    static void Map(int a) {
    }

}
```